# Is it an anti-pattern in Akka HTTP to pass around the request context for completion?

Tags: akka

Imagine I have a `JobsEndpoint` class, which contains a `JobSupervisor` class which then has two child actors, `RepositoryActor` and `StreamsSupervisorActor`.  The behavior for different requests to this top level `JobSupervisor` will need to be performed in the appropriate child actor.  For example, a request to store a job will be handled exclusively in the `RepositoryActor`, etc...

My question, then, is if it is an anti-pattern to pass the request context through these actors via the messages, and then complete the request as soon as it makes sense?

So instead of doing this:

```
Request -> Endpoint ~ask~> JobSupervisor ~ask~> RepositoryActor
           Response <- Endpoint <- JobSupervisor <-|return result
```

I could pass the `RequestContext` in my messages, such as `StoreJob(..., ctx: RequestContext)`, and then complete it in the `RepositoryActor`.

Answer (score 0):

I admittedly haven't been using Akka long but I see a few opportunities for improvement.

First, you are chaining "ask" calls which block threads. In some cases it's unavoidable but I think in your case, it is avoidable. When you block threads, you're potentially  hurting your throughput.

I would have the Endpoint send a message with it's ActorRef as a "reply to" field. That way, you don't have to block the Endpoint and JobSupervisor actors. Whenever Repository actor completes the operation, it can send the reply directly to Endpoint without having to traverse middlemen.

Depending on your messaging guarantee needs, the Endpoint could implement retrying and de-duplicating if necessary.

Ideally each actor will have everything it needs to process a message in the message. I'm not sure what your RequestContext includes but I would consider:

1) Is it hard to create one? This impacts testability. If the RequestContext is difficult to create, I would opt for pulling out just the needed members so that I could write unit tests.

2) Can it be serialized? If you deploy your actor system in a cluster environment, then you'll need to serialize the messages. Messages that are simple data holders work best.